ClientHttpResponse has null responseStream in Spring ResponseErrorHandler
I have to call an external API with RestTemplate but that API always return code 2xx. When there is an error, it will return the error json, so I am using ResponseErrorHandler to parse the body of the response to determine the error.
It looks like this:
public class RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
        boolean hasError = httpResponse.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError() ||
                httpResponse.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError();
        if (hasError) {
            return true;
        } else if (httpResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            String responseBody = convertStreamToString(httpResponse.getBody());
            // Logic check body
        }
        return false;
    }

But httpResponse.responseStream is always null so I could not get the response body to parse it.
Does Spring already read the stream somewhere else? Or I could not get response body inside hasError?

A couple of things here.
First, your hasError implementation needs to only return whether an error has occurred or not, reading the response here for successful calls doesn't really do anything.
@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    return response.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError() ||
            response.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError();
}

Secondly, you just need to implement the method to handle the errors (maybe just throw an exception and let your ControllerAdvice render an appropriate response?)
@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    throw new MyRestTemplateException(IOUtils.toString(response.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}

The exception class
public class MyRestTemplateException extends RuntimeException {
    public MyRestTemplateException(String string) {
        super(string);
    }
}

The controller advice
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyRestTemplateException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

